# Troubleshoot printing macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So with the help of the Stack Overflow community some time back, I created a printing macro for a worksheet that would read the worksheet and only print the number of pages that had information in it. It would read certain sections of rows and if not data had been entered, would print the correct number of pages. This allowed the user to just input the data and hit the print button to print the correct number of pages (rather than selecting File..Print...etc)

Here is the code that was used:

```
Sub LastRowInOneColumn()

    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Set MySheet = Worksheets("SIF Sheet")

    With MySheet

        Dim xLastRow As Long
        xLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        Select Case True

            Case xLastRow > 21 And xLastRow < 46

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Preview:=True

            Case xLastRow > 46 And xLastRow < 97

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=2, Preview:=True

            Case xLastRow > 98 And xLastRow < 149

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=3, Preview:=True

            Case xLastRow > 150 And xLastRow < 201

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=4, Preview:=True

            Case xLastRow > 202 And xLastRow < 253

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=5, Preview:=True

            Case xLastRow > 254 And xLastRow < 305

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=6, Preview:=True

            Case xLastRow > 306 And xLastRow < 357

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=7, Preview:=True

            Case xLastRow > 358 And xLastRow < 409

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=8, Preview:=True

            Case xLastRow > 410 And xLastRow < 461

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=9, Preview:=True

            Case xLastRow > 462 And xLastRow < 513

                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut From:=1, To:=10, Preview:=True

        End Select

    End With

End Sub
```

This was fine as the data that was being entered was in sections (1 account per section) however we recently have had to redesign it so it is no longer in sections. The way it is now
[image: Example Picture]

What I need help with is a script that will check row by row for data, infinitely and then print when it comes to the first row with no data, only those pages that have data.

Hope this makes sense.

I also found this bit of code so now I am super confused by which one I was using.

```
Sub LastRowInOneColumn()            
    If Range("C19") = "Enter any special posting instruction here." Then
        Range("C19:I26").ClearContents
    End If

    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Set MySheet = Worksheets("SIF Sheet")

    With MySheet
        Dim xLastRow As Long
        xLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Select Case True
            Case xLastRow < 500
                'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
                Worksheets("SIF Sheet").PrintOut
        End Select
    End With    
End Sub
```

The part I need the most help with is this:
The issue they are having is that say they enter information on lines 1-200, then delete the information on lines 175-200, it is still printing through 200, rather than through 175

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I need help with is a script that will check row by row for data,
>   infinitely and then print when it comes to the first row with no data

You can get the first row with no data with a method similar to the one used on the macro you found, like so:

```
With MySheet

    Dim xFirstEmptyRow As Long
    xFirstEmptyRow = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

End With
```

Link to .End method here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end

Comment: Your code works fantastic but we are still having the issue whereby if a user enters 200 rows of numbers, then deletes the last 25 rows, its still printing 200 rows instead of 175 rows.